# How many elements are there in $\mathbb {Z}_{27} \times M$ with order that is not a power of 3?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Consider the group $M=\{ \left( \begin{array}{cc}a & b \\0 & c \end{array} \right)|~ac\not = 0,~a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}_3\}$ with respect to ordinary multiplication of matrices. the question is how many elements of $~\mathbb {Z}_{27} \times M$ are there with order that is not a power of 3?

I know that the order of $M$ is $12$. Is there a way to solve this without writing all the elements of $M$ and see what their respective order in $M$?

P.S: this question is in the chapter of Lagrange's Theorem in my book so I can't use more advanced Theorems (like sylow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element $(n, m) \in \Bbb Z_{27}\times M$ has order $\operatorname{lcm}(|n|, |m|)$, which is a power of $3$ iff $|m|$ is a power of $3$ (remember that $|n|$ is either $1, 3, 9$ or $27$).

Comment: so I'm looking for all $(n,m)$ s.t $|m|\in \{1,3\}$ (or the complement of them)?

Comment: @dorsh605 Exactly.

Comment: Ok thanks. but now I have to find How many elements of order $3$ are there in $M$ so I still need to write down all the elements of $M$ and check their order. or is there an easy way to decide how many of them have order $3$?

Comment: @dorsh605 There is a better way. Letting $m = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, we get $$m^3 = \left(\begin{matrix}a&abc + 2b\\0&c\end{matrix}\right)$$(by using that $a^2 = c^2 = 1$, since they are both non-zero). Now, if this is supposed to be the identity matrix, then we must have $a = c = 1$, which makes the top right element into $3b = 0$, so $b$ can be anything. That means there are $2$ elements of order $3$ (corresponding to $b = 1$ and $b = 2$) and one element of order $1$ (the identity matrix), the other $9$ elements have order $2$ or $4$.

Comment: How do you know that the rest have order $2$ or $4$? why can't we have order $6$?

Comment: @dorsh605 You're right, I done goofed.

Comment: Ok, anyway it is not needed for the answer of this question. Thank you very much!

Comment: @dorsh605 Just because I felt I had to: $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2&2\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ have order $6$, but there are none of order $4$.